# How to implement Drawer and TabBar in StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I always use react-native-router-flux for navigation, but on this project I need to use react-navigation and I got some troubles with it. I need to implement drawer and tabBar inside stack navigator.

Problems:

1. I use header component from native-base library but i can't open
   drawer.
2. How to use my own customized component for drawer and tabBar?
3. Maybe I need to chage structure. I will consider any recommendations how to improve structure.

I used version 3 of react-navigation.

My code:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    loginFlow: { 
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        intro: { screen: Intro },
        login: { screen: Login },
        registration: { screen: Registration },
      }),
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
        }
    },
    mainFlow: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        MyDrawer: createDrawerNavigator({
            Dashboard: {
                screen: Home,
              },
              first: {
                screen: first,
              },
              second: {
                screen: second
              },
              third: {
                screen: third
              },
              last: {
                screen: last
              }
        }),

        // settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
          someTab: { 
            screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
              main: { screen: Home },
              firsrTab: { screen: Screen1 },
              secondTab: { screen: Screen2 },
              thirdTab: { screen: Screen3 },
              nextTab: { screen: Screen4 }
            }),
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null
            },
          }
  }),
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);

import React from 'react';
import { Header, Left, Icon, Right } from 'native-base';

const CustomHeader = (props) => {
    return(
        <Header>
            <Left>
                <Icon
                    name='menu'
                    onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}}
                />
            </Left>
        </Header>
    )
}

export { CustomHeader }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna consider the `SwitchNavigator` for the authentication flow instead of a `Stack at the top`  as it replaces the routes so that you can never navigate back to the login/signup/splash once you get into the application and for accessing Tabs and Drawer inside stack/switch, you can wrap the Drawer inside your top level navigator and tab inside the drawer.

So you root navigation would look like this.

```
export default RootNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginContainer},
  Application: {screen: AppDrawer},
});
```

Your drawer navigator should be like the following:

```
const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  ApplicationTab: {screen: TabBar},
  ... other screen that you might want to use in drawer navigation.
}, {
   contentComponent : (props) => <MyCustomDrawer {...props} />
});
```

and, Tab Navigator would be,

```
const TabBar = createBottomTabNavigator({
  TabScreen1: {screen: Tab1},
  ... other tabs...
}, {
  tabBarComponent : (props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />
});
```

**If you put each of those navigators in single file then please do declare Tab before Drawer and Drawer before the Switch, else it would give errors.**

In my experience, customising drawer navigator is very simple and fruitful but customising tab is not, there aren't proper API doc for the same and community answers are also somewhat misleading.
BUT, with normal use cases and for most of the vivid ones too, you can do your job without needing to override the default one as it is already highly operable and customisable in terms of icons, materialism and each tab exposes its on `onPress` that can also be easily overriden.

and as you as the drawer is not getting operated from/via the header, then can you please ensure that the `navigation` prop you are using to operate the drawer `open` `close` or `toggle` action is the one given by drawer ?

Comment: I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/surajj2223/d3bd925d67bc01281bdeea8599416dca) for you from one of my project in which i have developed custom drawer component. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also I can see you have used `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()`  from the CustomHeader, you should use `props.navigation.openDrawer()` and also ensure that you are passing the props to your `CustomHeader` correctly.

Comment: @Hannibal can you post your code of where you are using your CustomerHeader component ? Also you might want to check the gist I shared in above comment. It might be helpful for you for coding style.

Comment: @surajmalviya Hi, are you using react-navigation v3?

Comment: @ArchNoob I was using v2. Does using v3 changes the way the navigators behave I don't believe it as there are no special changes that I have seen in v3 ? Still I will find that out and get back to you if thats the case.

Comment: @surajmalviya I'm not sure if there are major groundbreaking changes but I asked because when I read react-navigation docs I didn't see any option for custom components examples and thought it is removed.

Comment: @ArchNoob I have gone to the doc and have seen that the options are still there. 
for eg. see [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent). Although I will try it myself with v3 surely. :)